# Flash memory scheduling algorithms?

Tags: algorithm, filesystems, flash-memory

I'm trying to do some research around file systems and I've probably confused myself. I've got to disk scheduling algorithms for devices with discs such as SCAN and CSCAN, but I was wondering what the equivalents are for flash memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some research approaches like in [the 2009 paper "A New I/O Scheduler for Solid State Devices"](https://mathcircle.tamu.edu/techpubs/2009/TAMU-ECE-2009-02.pdf).
However, I am not aware that any of this is used in practice. The "Noop" scheduler, which means that the scheduler is not reordering requests, seems to be the standard scheduler to use for SSDs.

Anyway, a lot more should change in todays OS to really perform with modern and future SSDs as pointed out in [this MSST 2010 paper](http://storageconference.org/2010/Papers/MSST/Seppanen.pdf).

Comment: The first link is not accessible. Can you please post the name of the paper or another link?

Comment: Changed. The people allow only access via https, but then they don't use a valid certificate.